# How to send SMS message to another android device from my app

Tags: java, android, sms

I declared these two variables in order to send a text message to declared number:

```
private String text="Hi";
private String emergencyNum="00962789113300";
```

Then in onCreat() method I wrote this:

```
SmsManager sender= SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage(emergencyNum, null, text, null, null);
```

Unfortunately, the message was not sent and I got not responding status for my app. Could you help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Nitish 's answer makes sense, but it could be a number of problems. You really should check logcat for an error message and attach the log to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place the following permission into `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```